# Email attachment empty PHP4

Tags: php, email

Ok, php4 - I get it.  That said, for many reasons it's not possible to upgrade to php5 and use phpMailer - as much as I'd like to.  I've searched around and there's no other answer presented.  So, here's the problem.  I create a text file /tmp2/tmporder2

The code below sends the email fine with the attachment, but the attachment is 0 bytes, NADA.

```
<?php
$path = '/tmp2';
$filename = 'tmporder2';
$mailto = 'dave@powerfulhosting.com';
$from_mail = 'estore order receipt';
 $from_name = 'bagelworks order';
 $replyto = '';
 $subject = 'TESTING EMAIL ATTACHMENT';

    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $message=$handle;

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
?>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the file was properly read? You'r simply assuming your fopen/fread stuff succeeded.

Comment: I see `$filename = 'tmporder2';` but no file extension. Plus you have `$path = '/tmp2';` - Try addding a `/` in it, as in `$path = '/tmp2/';`

Answer (score 0):

When trying your script from the root of my server using:

```
$path = '/tmp2/';
$filename = 'tmporder2.txt'; // I renamed it with an `.txt` extension to test
```

it did not send it and received many errors.

However, when I tested the same script but removing the `/` at the beginning of `tmp2` and adding a `/` at the end such as:

```
$path = 'tmp2/';
$filename = 'tmporder2.txt';
```

it worked and sent me an Email with the file attached.

Try running my example code from the `root` of your server, creating a sub-folder called `tmp2` and inserting `tmporder2.txt` with any kind of text inside it, and try it again.

### Extra error in code

I also noticed a few more errors in your code.

For instance, this line `$message=$handle;` That should not be part of your message if it's to be sent as an attachment.

- This line `if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {`

The 3rd parameter is the where the message body goes into.

I replaced it with `if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {` where the `$message` is now `$message = "Hello there";` which will appear in the body. I received an error message:

> Warning: mail() expects parameter 3 to be string

---

#### You're welcome to try out the following script that is working very well.

#### To use it, you will need to make changes to these:

```
$name = 'image.jpg';
// The path to the image with the file name:
$fileatt = "images/".$name;
```

#### Which is within the code below: (pre-tested)

```
<?php

// Set who this goes to:
$to = array('Your Name','email@example.com');
// Give the message a subject:
$subject = 'Some subject';
// Set who this message is from:
$from = array("My Company", "email@example.com");

// Create the header information:
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$random_hash}x"; 
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$mime_boundary.'"' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '.$to[0].' <'.$to[1].'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from[0].' <'.$from[1].'>' . "\r\n";

// Build the message (can have HTML in it) message:
$message = 'This is an <b>HTML message</b> it comes with an attachment!'."\n\n".
// Do not edit this part of the message:
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message . "\n\n";
// The image that you would like to send (filename only):
$name = 'image.jpg';
// The path to the image with the file name:
$fileatt = "images/".$name;

$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
// Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$fileatt_name = $name; 

// Read the file attachment:
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file); 

// Create sendable information
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

// Finalize the message with attachment
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n";
unset($data);
unset($file);
unset($fileatt);
unset($fileatt_type);
unset($fileatt_name);

// Send the message:
mail($to[1], $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Email sent";

?>
```